# Copy of original monopoly game patent

Tags: patent-services

My grandfather had a company called "Schmid Game Company". He created a game called "Stock Market" which he copyrighted in 1959.  During this process he obtained two copies of the original Dec. 31, 1935 Monopoly game patent.  They are both stamped with the attorneys stamp "HOWARD L. FISCHER" Patent Attorney Engineer, 911 Foshay Tower MINNEAPOLIS 2, MINNESOTA. They also have handwritten on them the patent number and "Darrow".  My grandfather passed away quite a long time ago.  My father passed away about 5 years ago and I found these in a box from his house. Any idea what the value of these would be and who might be interested in them?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks about the collectable value of patent documents.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Value of an Original Vintage Patent?](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/10679/value-of-an-original-vintage-patent)

Comment: Thank you I did see that, but thought because mine was stamped with the law office stamp that it would prove that it was not just a copy printed off the internet.  Sounds like this is not the proper forum to ask about values.  Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @RobertCartaino Monopoly being famous might mean the document has collectible value. Either was I think it is off topic for this site.